# Unify two queries for current_user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following associations:

A `User has_many Hosts` and a `Host has_many Orders`

I have nested routes for Hosts and Orders, so when a user wants to see Orders, it will have to be through a Host (`/hosts/:id/orders`)

I want to avoid users accessing other users orders, so I have this in my index action:

```
def index
  host = current_user.hosts.find(params[:host_id])
  redirect_to :back, alert: 'Host was not found' if host.nil?
  orders = host.orders.includes(:order_state).order('id ASC')
end
```

As you can see I am hitting the DB twice. One to find if the host exists for current_user, and another one to find the orders for this host.

How can I do this in just one query?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
orders = Order.joins(:host)
              .includes(:order_state)
              .where(hosts: { user_id: current_user.id, id: params[:host_id] })
              .order('orders.id ASC')
redirect_to :back, alert: 'Orders for selected host not found' unless orders.any?
```

If you want to give user alert for host not found you can't do it with one query.

Comment: Will that syntax for `unless` work if you don't use `()` for `redirect_to`?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by `sufleR`, there probably isn't an easy way how to distinguish between `no orders for the given host` and `host not found`. The code, however, can be simpler:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hosts
  has_many :orders, through: :hosts # !!!
end

orders = current_user.orders.includes(:order_state).order(:id).
  where(host_id: params[:host_id])
```